# Shiism- who leads prayers during Imam-e-Zamana, when he's present in the masjid/praying place?

Tags: salat, shiism

Sunni scholars have consensus that leader of Muslims leads prayers when he's present.

I want to know stand of Shia regarding lead of prayers when Imam-e-Zamana (Imam Mahdi) is present.

Answer (score -1):

```
                                  In the name of Allah
```

> Shiism- who leads prayers during imam-e-zamana, when he's present in
> the masjid/praying place?

To the best of my knowledge, Imam Zaman (Mahdi [a.j.]) will lead the Salah (prayer) --of Jama'-- and Jesus will also say prayer behind him.

Source:

- [hawzah.net](https://hawzah.net/fa/Hadith/View/11208/-%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%AA%D8%AF%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AD%D8%B6%D8%B1%D8%AA-%D8%B9%DB%8C%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85-%D9%85%D9%87%D8%AF%DB%8C-%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C%D9%87%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85)

Comment: Question doesn't asking about it in the presence of Jesus (as).